# Intersection of two sparse graph

Tags: matlab, graph

What is the best time order way for finding common edges of two graphs with equal number of nodes in matlab? I have both edges list and adjacency matrix and graph is sparse.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the edge list use:

```
commonEdges = intersect(edgesA, edgesB, 'rows')
```

For the adjacency matrix use:

```
commonAdjacency = adjacencyA & adjacencyB;
```

Comment: I think in a graph with m edges, order of intersect is O(m^2), is there any way for intersection of sorted list?

Comment: @user137927: I don't think these solutions are of complexity `O(m^2)`. They both should be log-linear.